# num not summing right

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

```
def one():
    return total.set(total.get() + 1.2)
def two():
    return total.set(total.get() + 2.0)
def three():
    return total.set(total.get() + 1.6)
def four():
    return total.set((total.get() + 2.0)
total = IntVar()
total.set(0)
b1 = Button(app,text = "one ",width = 10,command = one)
b1.pack()
b2 = Button(app,text = "two ",width = 10,command = two)
b2.pack()
b3 = Button(app,text = "three ",width = 10,command = three)
b3.pack()
b4 = Button(app,text = "four ",width = 10,command = four)
b4.pack()
```

total is summing wrong with the numbers . Like total is 2.2 and you press b1 and it adds to 3.2 , not 3.4 . I have tried to put a float in a lot of places ( after return , before total.get() ... ) but it didnt work . I guess the problem with total as IntVar() , I dont understand what this is .

Comment: Try replacing `IntVar()` with `DoubleVar()`

Comment: Correct , replacing with DoubleVar() make it work

Comment: Oh good, I'll make it an answer and you can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're using an `IntVar` when you should be using a `DoubleVar`. The `IntVar` will truncate values to round integer numbers. The `DoubleVar` will allow you to use floating point numbers like you are in your `one` through `three` functions.